# Prompting user input to find a certain column value in a CSV in PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of NBA players which have Columns: `Player, games played  (G), minutes played (MP), player efficiency rating (PER), true shooting percentage (TS%), 3 point attempt rate (3PAr), free throw rate (FTr), offensive rebound percentage (ORB%), defensive rebound percentage (DRB%), total rebound percentage (TRB%), assist percentage (AST%), block percentage (BLK%), steal percentage (STL%), and turnover percentage (TOV%)`

within these rows are column values of numbers that match the statistic.

I want the user to input a certain player name, and then input what statistic they want to see and have the code present that statistic to them.

so far I have:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/francis/Desktop/nba.csv")
def retrieve_player_stat(df):
    print("Welcome to Retrieve a Player Statistic!!!! This function will help you find a certain player's desired statistic!!")
    playername = input("What player? (First name Last name)")
    query = df[df['Player'].str.match(playername)]
    if len(query) > 0:
        statistic = input("Which statistic? *Please input value within parantheses*  games played(G), minutes played(MP), player efficiency rating(PER), true shooting_percentage(TS%), 3_point_attempt_rate(3PAr), free throw rate(FTr), offensive rebound percentage(ORB%), defensive rebound percentage(DRB%), total rebound percentage(TRB%), assist_percentage(AST%), block percentage (BLK%), steal percentage(STL%), and turnover percentage(TOV%)")
        result = query[statistic].get(0)
        print(result)
    else:
        print("Invalid player name")
```

This code allows me to input the player name and then the statistic I desire. However, it always outputs "None". Here is what my CSV file looks like as well in the picture.[image]

Comment: The code you posted already does that

Comment: Nah I get an error. ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Post your error and what line triggers the error

Comment: ---> 33 if playername == df.Player:  1479             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1480             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand the question phrasing (probably just me :D) but you could try this:

```
def Michaels_stat():
    G = 1072
#and so on ~~~
    i = input("Games played (G) #etc.")
    if i == 'G':
        print(G)
    elif:
        #etc.
if playername == "Michael Jordan":
    print(Michaels_stats())
```

I am not sure if this is what you want but you could see if 'G' is inputted then you print the 'games played' stat :)

Answer (score 0):

There could be other better options, but you can try this, you need to take care of what you enter into `statistic`, meaning, `statictic` should contain the complete and proper name of the column.

```py
def retrieve_player_stat(df):
    print("Welcome to Retrieve a Player Statistic!!!! This function will help you find a certain player's desired statistic!!")
    playername = input("What player? (First name Last name)")
    query = df[df['Player'].str.match(playername)]
    if len(query) > 0:
        query = query.iloc[0]
        statistic = input("""Which statistic?  ... """)
        result = query[statistic]
        print(result)
    else:
        print("Invalid player name")
```

Comment: This code carries my program even further. However, the column values in the CSV itself actually are the shorter terms such as "TS%". When I try to use this code, it always gives me "None" as a statistics result.

Comment: try printing query and see what it outputs before the if statement. Also you can check it manually in the csv file if the column has a null value or not...

Comment: I added a print(query) before the if len statement and still am given a "None"

Comment: What is it giving in the literal sense? like is it actually giving "None" or "invalid player name"

Comment: Yeah, it just literally says "None". It allows me to input the player name, then what statistic, and then it just outputs "None"

Comment: The value for the player's statistic that you want is `None` or blank in the csv. Check it manually in the csv for the player and the statistic... two consecutive commas mean `None`

Comment: Its not null in the CSV

Comment: Could you share a few entries from the csv with the header...? Add them to the question

Comment: I will revise the entire question right now and post it. One moment

Comment: I see the issue with my code... let me see what can be done...

Comment: You are a beast illusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using `fuzzywuzzy` and `choices` package to make it a little more robust:

```
import pandas as pd

#pip install fuzzywuzzy
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

#pip install choice
import choice


df = pd.read_csv("/Users/francis/Desktop/nba.csv")


def retrieve_player_stat(df):
    print("Welcome to Retrieve a Player Statistic!!!! This function will help you find a certain player's desired statistic!!")
    playername = input("What player? (First name Last name) ")
    
    df['score'] = df.apply(lambda x : fuzz.ratio(x.Player, playername), axis=1)
    df = df.sort_values('score', ascending=False)
    
    if len(df[df['score'] > 60]) > 1:
        player_list = list(df[df['score'] > 60]['Player'])
        player_input =  choice.Menu(player_list).ask()
        query = df[df['Player'] == player_input]
    
    else:
        query = df.head(1)
    
    player = query.iloc[0]['Player']
    
    cols = [ x for x in df.columns if x not in ['Rk','Player','Pos','score']]
    stat_input = choice.Menu(cols).ask()
    
    value = query.iloc[0][stat_input]
    
    print ('{player} - {stat}: {value}'.format(player=player,stat=stat_input,value=value))
    
    
retrieve_player_stat(df)
```

**Example: if players have similar names**

```
Welcome to Retrieve a Player Statistic!!!! This function will help you find a certain player's desired statistic!!

What player? (First name Last name) Stef curry
Make a choice:
 0: Seth Curry
 1: Stephen Curry

Enter number or name; return for next page

? 1

Make a choice:
 0: Age
 1: Tm
 2: G
 3: GS
 4: MP
 5: FG
 6: FGA
 7: FG%
 8: 3P
 9: 3PA

Enter number or name; return for next page

? 

 0: 3P%
 1: 2P
 2: 2PA
 3: 2P%
 4: eFG%
 5: FT
 6: FTA
 7: FT%
 8: ORB
 9: DRB

Enter number or name; return for next page

? 

 0: TRB
 1: AST
 2: STL
 3: BLK
 4: TOV
 5: PF
 6: PTS

Enter number or name; return for next page

? 6

Stephen Curry - PTS: 104
```

**Example: if there is a typo/case sensitive issue**

```
Welcome to Retrieve a Player Statistic!!!! This function will help you find a certain player's desired statistic!!

What player? (First name Last name) jAmEs HaRrDin
Make a choice:
 0: Age
 1: Tm
 2: G
 3: GS
 4: MP
 5: FG
 6: FGA
 7: FG%
 8: 3P
 9: 3PA

Enter number or name; return for next page

? 4

James Harden - MP: 2483
```